# C++ best practice - duplicate an object with class method, class constructor, or instance method

Tags: class, implementation

I want the classes in a small library I'm working on to support duplication of instance objects, so I wonder what is the best practice to add this feature.

Duplication with class method:

```
Myclass* obj2 = MyClass::duplicate(obj1);
```

...class constructor:

```
Myclass* obj2 = MyClass(obj1);
```

...instance method:

```
Myclass* obj2 = obj1.duplicate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance method is probably the best way ahead. I am taking a leaf out of Java's clone() method. You can have a super class with an empty implementation and you just use inheritance and let subclasses customize their versions.